# How to specify edge length in Networkx based off of edge weight

Tags: networkx

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

#Generate graph with 4 nodes
erdo_graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(4, 0.7, directed=False)

#Add edge weights
for u,v,d in erdo_graph.edges(data=True):
    d['weight'] =  np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 7), p=[0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.2,])

#If you want to print out the edge weights:
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(erdo_graph,'weight')

print("Here are the edge weights: ", labels)

#Following "Networkx Spring Layout with different edge values" link that you supplied:
initialpos = {1:(0,0), 2:(0,3), 3:(0,-1), 4:(5,5)}
pos = nx.spring_layout(erdo_graph, weight='weight', pos=initialpos)
nx.draw_networkx(erdo_graph, pos)
plt.show()
```

Whenever I try to position the nodes based off of a layout, I expect nodes that are connected by a lower edge weight to be closer to each other, but that doesn't seem to be the case. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Networkx Spring Layout with Different Edge Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797990/networkx-spring-layout-with-different-edge-values)

Comment: @Joel That seems to only work if I'm adding edges. The way that I have it configured is that I generate a graph: `erdo_graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(4, 0.7, directed=False)` and then add edge weights: `for u,v,d in erdo_graph.edges(data=True):
    d['weight'] =  np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 7), p=[0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2])` When I do that it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Joel I have updated my original question to contain a working example.

Comment: I've checked it (btw, you need to update p to have more entries), and it's there, but hard to see without more difference between the weights.  Put several orders of magnitude difference in the weights and note that large weights means shorter distances. (e.g., replace x by 10**x)

Comment: @RedShift your code doesn't run, it crashes with `ValueError: a and p must have same size`

Comment: THe bug @ValentinLorentz mentions is in this line `d['weight'] =  np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 7), p=[0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.2,])`.  This is because the first argument has length 6 and the second has length 4.  Once this is fixed the next problem is that `p` needs to sum to 1.